# Numerically integrating the results of a function, which depend on one variable, in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a one-variable-function y=f(x) which is too complicated to integrate myself. So I intended to sum up all results (y's) given by maybe thousands of x's.

Is there any function in Excel that could do the numerical integration in a single cell?

For example, that I would take

- A1 as x
- B1 as `y=f(x)`
- C1 as the calculator function which calculates (from x=1 to x=n) and sums up all the y's (from f(1) to f(n)).

AUTOSUM and SUMPRODUCT would not fit this purpose I suppose.

**EDIT** (To elaborate on the issue):

Here is the original function:
[image: original function.].

Here Fn1n2 is a function of 2 variables n1 and n2. I will have to keep, say n1 constant and solve for a 1000 different values of n2 and sum them up.

Then I would increase n1 one by one (for 1000 times), solving for n2 and summing up the results again and again.

This means that I would have to solve for a 1000x1000 times which would take maybe an hour to write manually.

Here is an example of the situation:
[image: example]

Comment: Could you please add some sample data, would be easier to understand your issue.

Comment: Of course. I tried to make it as clear as possible in the edit section above.

Answer (score 0):

***[Edit: I've added images for n1 and n2 going from 1 to 10 and simplified it. Thx to @Máté Juhász for the feedback.]***

There are a few approaches for this. 
It seems like every time I answer I first start with saying "Use tables". This advice is very good here as well, because you want each formula to be uniform for the entire column, and it gives the benefit of storing each column's formula *once* instead of once per cell.

So,

## Make a Table for Your Formula

1. Change A1 to "n1"
2. Change B1 to "n2=1"
3. Change C1 to "n2=2"
4. Highlight B1..C1
5. Drag the dot in the lower right corner of the selected range out to ALM1 to get to "n2=1000" [image]
6. In the "Insert" ribbon, insert a table. In the Create Table dialog, change the data range to be `=$A$1:$ALM$2` and be sure that "My table has headers" is checked.
7. In A2, add a formula of `ROW()-1`[image]
8. Copy this sheet to a new sheet in your workbook for later.
9. Okay, now comes your math. Add your formula into b2, but instead of n1, use `(ROW()-1)`, and instead of n2, use `(COLUMN()-1)`. I simply made a multiplication table so my formula (n1*n2) was `=(ROW()-1)*(COLUMN()-1)`.
10. Click the "Table Design" ribbon that will only be available if your cursor is within the table, and select "Total Row" and "First Column" in the ribbon. ("First Column" is only for cosmetic purposes, btw.)
11. Change B3 to `=SUM([n2=1])+IF(COLUMN()=2,0,A3)`
12. Edit B3, Highlight the mention of "A3", then click on the cell A3. This should change B3's formula to something like `=SUM([n2=1])+IF(COLUMN()=2,0,Table1[[#Totals],[n1]])`
13. Highlight B2..B3 and drag or copy the formulae all the way out through the rest of the row to column ALM. You should now have a table with a total row that gives the summation of n1=1 and n2=1 to 1000 [image]
14. To change n1 to 1000, at the left end of the "Table Design" ribbon is a "Resize table" button. Click it and change the table size to `=$A$1:$ALM$1002`[image]

## Sums

If this is all you need, you can stop now. But, if you need the sum for any given value of n1 and n2 through 1000, then we could go one of two ways:

#### Summation Option 1: Easy But Slow

In this case, we have two tabs. The above one will contain a table containing the "un-summed" formula values. And then the one we'll create, when we're trying to sum the values of n1=(1 to 4) and n2(1 to 4), we get all of the values by doing the following:

`Table1[[#Headers],[n1]]` gives us the top-left cell of that first table.

`OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[n1]],1,1)` gives the cell one down and one to the right, i.e. the first data cell where n1=1 and n2=1.

Offset has optional 4th and 5th arguments that specify the height and width of the range of cells returned. Using those optional arguments, `=OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[n1]],1,1,`*n1*`,`*n2*`)` gives us all of the values we want to sum up!

So, to exploit this,

1. go to that new sheet we created in step 9.
2. In B2 of this second sheet, change the formula to `=SUM(OFFSET(Table1[[#Headers],[n1]],1,1,row()-1,column()-1))`  In this way, when n1 is 5 and n2 is 3, you'll be getting the sum of the rectangle starting in Table1's B2 cell, 5 rows high and 3 columns wide.
3. Copy cell B2 to the clipboard.
4. Highlight C2..ALM2
5. Paste
6. Go get some coffee. If you really want to go out to n1=1000 and n2=1000, the previous Sum method will take a very long time! That table of cells using that SUM method will have 1000*1000 cells, and every one will look at Sheet1!B2, 999^2 of those cells will also include Sheet1!C3, etc., so that the SUM() formula where n1=1000 and n2=1000 will look at *a million cells* even though all but one of which have already been summed before! [image] *(Note, I changed the table style for the second sheet to "Table Style Medium 4")*

#### Summation Option 2: Sum by Rows, then Sum by Columns

Instead we can make something much more efficient, having Excel build running sums. The following screenshots show this optimized method. **Note that I renamed the tables** (and the tabs, but that doesn't matter) which is why the following formulas use "Formula" and "N1Sums" rather than "Table1" and "Table2".

Instead of that sum table, we can use two tables.

The second table's column B formula is `=Formula[@[n2=1]]+IF(COLUMN()=2,0,[@n1])`, and then you'll have to drag it through the other columns, so that column C's formula is `=Formula[@[n2=2]]+IF(COLUMN()=2,0,[@[n2=1]])`. This will have running sums for each row. In effect, this formula says "add my corresponding cell in the first table plus the cell to my left."

The third table is similar, except its formula says "add my corresponding cell in the *second* table plus the cell *above me*." Column B's formula is `=N1Sums[@[n2=1]]+IF(ROW()=2,0,OFFSET([@[n2=1]],-1,0))`, and then you'll have to drag it to the other columns so that Column C's formula is `=N1Sums[@[n2=2]]+IF(ROW()=2,0,OFFSET([@[n2=2]],-1,0))`

The following screenshots show this optimized method.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: your answer my be correct, but it's long and complicated:(, difficult to follow. An image to show how it looks like and whether it really works would help a lot.

Comment: Updated with screenshots and other improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with using only one cell, two different variables as in your example:

[image]

- columns A and B contains values for n1 and n2

  - you need to give both as ranges, e.g. `1:10`
  - you can only use natural numbers, within the row range of your sheet (so no negative and zero)
  - even if you need only one number enter it as a range (as e.g. in A2)
  - Excel likely will try to convert your input to a number / date, so either:

    - change number format of columns A, B to Text BEFORE entering values
    - or type `'` at the beginning of each cell (`'1:100`)
  - you can specify a range only for one of the variables (otherwise you get an error like in row 5)
- sample function in column C is:

  - `=SUM(COS(ROW(INDIRECT(A2))+ROW(INDIRECT(B2)))+SIN(ROW(INDIRECT(A2))+ROW(INDIRECT(B2))))`
  - which mean: `Sum(Cos(n1+n2)+Sin(n1+n2))`
  - it's an array formula, so you need to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER after typing it.